# Inbound Email handler - Status being set as 'Sent' instead of 'New'

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, inboundservices

I have the following Email handler Class:

```
global class InsertReplyEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope){
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    if(email.subject.contains('Case:')){
        system.debug(Email.subject);
        String CaseNumberExtract = email.subject.substringAfter('Case:').deleteWhitespace(); 
        Case c = [select id from Case where CaseNumber = :CaseNumberExtract]; 
        EmailMessage newEmail = new EmailMessage();
        newEmail.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;   
        newEmail.FromName = email.fromName;
        newEmail.ToAddress = email.toAddresses[0];
        newEmail.Subject = email.subject;
        newEmail.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
        newEmail.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody; 
        newEmail.RelatedToID = c.id;   
        newEmail.Incoming = true;
        insert newEmail; 
    }

    return null;    
}}
```

It's working fine but my issue is that all the emails are coming in with a status of 'Sent'. I want the status to be 'New'. I've tried to set the status as new in the below class but i get an error saying bad picklist value when i test the class.

Does anyone know how I can get the status to work as i'm hoping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can set the status value with the sequence number.

0 - New
1 - Read 
2 - Replied
3 - Sent
4 - Forwarded
5 - Draft

So it could be like this

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
emailMessage.status = '3'; // email was sent
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot Customize the status Value to other than this as you wish.You can change values within this **New, Read, Replied, Sent, Forwarded, or Draft.** Email Is Incoming so Status will be sent.

[image]

[Check here for Email Message Field Details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)